# Limit return items on chalice and lambda service

Tags: python, aws-lambda, chalice

I'm writing serverless apps in python and deploy use chalice, lambda, aws

Just a quick question: 
I would like to limit the number of the item returned from the API.

Maximum 1000 items per day

Maximum 200 items per hour

Here is sample API:

```
@app.route('/items', authorizer=authorizer)
def get_items():
    params = app.current_request.query_params
    tickets = AvaiableItem(params).get()
    return { 'items': items.serialize() }
```

How can I config the limit number?

Answer (score 0):

Chalice does not have any builtin support for API throttling yet, but you can monitor the GitHub issue [Add support for throttling per route](https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/615).

In the interim, you can manually configure throttling via the AWS Console as described in [Throttle API Requests for Better Throughput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html). You could of course also do this via boto3 if desired.